# Guidelines when using camera in android studio

Tags: android-studio, camera, android-camera-intent

I'm currently working on an app in Android Studio where I need to capture an image using the camera on the phone. The image must be very specific and not contain any background noise.

The way I want to solve this problem is by adding a box to the camera preview indicating the *region of interest (ROI)*. After that the image can be cropped in a way that only the content of the ROI is present.

*How do I add this box to define ROI?*

In my mind it would be perfect if it was a thin white line.

*Can I do it if I use the Image Capture Intent or do I have to create my own camera app?*

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - is that what you're after?

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera--mobile-11458

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but unfortunately it's not quite what I'm looking for. 
In the tutorial you linked to you take the picture and afterwards you manually define the region of interest which the image is cropped to. 

What I'm looking for is a way to add a box to the camera app before the picture is taken. Said in an other way adding thin guidelines on top of the real time camera content. This is for instance seen in many QR code readers where the box indicates the area where the QR code is.

Comment: I'm not too sure that you'll be able to inject a box into the default camera app. You might have to build your own cam_preview activity. Does the roi need to be adjustable or responsive? If not - you could layer an ImageView over top of a SurfaceView... and then load a .png of your 'roi box' into the ImageView. You can set the transparency with setAlpha().  I use a similar technique to overlay an image over my cam_preview (which is a SurfaceView) to take before / after photos. You would need to then manually process the captured data to apply any cropping before saving it to file.

Comment: Cheers Scott. That answer was what I was afraid of... It seems to be a rather large project. Does anyone know where I could get some inspiration?